# Defining a recursive function in a Prototype class?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I'm trying to create an image rotator class that cycles through an arbitrary number of images in an unordered list. Is it possible to define a recursive function within a class declaration? E.g:

```
var Rotator = Class.create() {
 initialize: function() {
  do something...

  this.rotate();
 }

 rotate: function() {
   do something...

   this.rotate()
 }
}
```

It currently throws an error stating "this.rotate() is not a function"

Comment: Try it. It looks like it should work fine to me.

Comment: That should work, but you want a condition when the recusive method should return.

Comment: @btl: We've all been so focussed on your saying you wanted to create a recursive function that we ignored the first sentence of your post. My suspicion is that you don't want a recursive function at all, and the problem you're having is how you're calling it. Updated my answer in case that's it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Answer:

What you have there should work (except for a couple of what I think are typos; below), because you're accessing the function from the property. Note that that means you'll re-enter the top-most (most sub-classed) `rotate` function if you're using inheritance, because that's the one that's assigned to the instance `rotate` property.

You said that it's saying that `this.rotate` is not a function. How are you calling it? Because if you're doing something like this:

```
var r = new Rotator();
setInterval(r.rotate, 1000);
```

or (within `rotate`):

```
setInterval(this.rotate, 1000);
```

...that's not going to work, because you're just passing the function (not its context) to `setInterval`. This would work:

```
var r = new Rotator();
setInterval(r.rotate.bind(r), 1000);
```

or (within `rotate`):

```
setInterval(this.rotate.bind(this), 1000);
```

That uses [Function#bind](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/function/prototype/bind/) to create a function that will set the correct context. More about functions vs. methods in Javascript in [this post](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html).

#### Typos:

```
var Rotator = Class.create() {
...
}
```

should be

```
var Rotator = Class.create({
...
});
```

You also need a comma between the two functions in the object literal notation you're using. So with those cleaned up it's:

```
var Rotator = Class.create({ // <= open brace *within* the parens

    initialize: function() {
        // do something...

        this.rotate();
    },                       // <= missing comma was here

    rotate: function() {
        // do something...

        this.rotate();
    }

    return pubs;
});                          // <= close the braces and parens here
```

#### Named functions (and typo-avoidance, and private functions):

FWIW, you can avoid typos like leaving out the comma between functions and *also* get all the benefits of your functions having [real *names*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html) (as opposed to being anonymous functions bound to properties) *plus* getting private class-wide functions (if that's useful to you). This is the idiom I mostly use (although I use a helper to make the syntax a small bit cleaner; the below is raw Prototype):

```
var Rotator = Class.create((function(){
    var pubs = {};

    pubs.initialize = initialize;
    function initialize() {
        // do something...

        this.rotate();
    }

    pubs.rotate = rotate;
    function rotate() {
        // do something...

        this.rotate();
    }

    return pubs;
})());
```

More on that idiom (and why you can't combine the `pubs` and `function` links above) in [the linked post](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html).

Comment: @btl: Have you checked for those typos?

Comment: @T.J. Thank you for clarifying this. The problem was in fact with binding to the correct context. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: @btl: No worries! Yeah, when I re-read the question, I suddenly thought: Doh! We're all missing the point. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, so long as you're confident that "this" will be the right thing. There are other ways to do it, but they have unfortunate disadvantages. You can give the function a name (ie, after the `function` keyword), but that can cause problems in IE.  You can also refer to a function via `arguments.callee`, but I've learned that that has bizarre performance problems, plus the whole `arguments` thing is kind-of deprecated because it's weird.

Comment: @Pointy Indeed, I was using "this" out of its proper scope. Thank you.